# How to get Timezone by passing abbreviation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I'm using Momentjs and as of now i'm getting date and time by doing the following steps

```
 var TimeZone = moment.tz("Asia/Kolkata").format('LLLL');
```

but i need to get time and date by passing abbreviation for instance

```
var TimeZone = moment.tz("IST").format('LLLL');
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Momentjs but I can provide u JS solution to do the same thing.
As i have understood from ur problem that ".tz" method only accepts full time zone name instead of short form. So u can use JS prototypal inheritance to achieve this outcome.
What u have to do is make another method of ur own with a dictionary object and extend "moment" object with ur features. Refer the code:

```
var tzMap = {
    "IST" :  "Asia/Kolkata",
    "UST" : "America/LA"   // this I only took for example i don't know it exist 
                              or not
}
moment.__proto__.timezone = function(tzStr){
    if(Object.hasOwnProperty(tzStr)){
         tzStr = tzMap[tzStr];
    } 
    return this.tz(tzStr);
} 

// now instead of using 
// moment.tz("Asia/Kolkata").format('LLLL');

// U can use
 var TimeZone = moment.timezone("Asia/Kolkata").format('LLLL');
// or
var TimeZone = moment.timezone("IST").format('LLLL');
```